# AVFoundation – captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

iOS 4.3 Beta 1

I dunno what's going on, but somehow the MetaDictionary of the sampleBuffer is missing in the new Beta. Can anyone approve this?

I always got the MetaDictionaty like this

```
CFDictionaryRef metadataDictionary = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, CFSTR("MetadataDictionary"), NULL);
```

this is now null, and I cannot figure out why? Somehow I am even not able to figure out all the available keys of the sampleBuffer. So therefore I would need some help or a fix that I still get the metadataDictionary.

update: for additional information i create the sampleBufferDelegate like this

```
dispatch_queue_t my_queue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", NULL);
[videoOut setSampleBufferDelegate:delegate queue:my_queue];
```

Comment: Regarding to the Release Notes has nothing changed in this particular part of the AV Foundation Framework, just in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try the constant `kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary` in place of your string there in the second parameter. They may have changed its value.